# How to update a QStringListModel?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I have the following code:

```
QStringListModel* m=new QStringListModel(gc.get_lista_file());
ui->lista_immagini_listView->setModel(m);
```

where `gc.get_lista_file()` returns a `QStringList` object and `lista_immagini_listView` is a `QListView`.

I need to update my `lista_immagini_listView` adding a string when I press a button, but if I add my new string to my `QStringList` object it doesn't update my model (I read the `QStringList` is passed by copy, so it isn't connected to the model). So, I have to update my `QStringListModel` but in this way I have to update 2 object (`QStringList` and `QStringListModel`) and doesn't seem a good practice.

What is the best way (if exists) to resolve it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`QStringListModel` does not allow you to simply add a string (sadly). Simply updating the `QStringList` does not work because the model stores a copy of the list.

There are basically two ways to get the desired behavior:

**1. Reset:**
This is the simple way. You just take the list from the model, add the string and reassign it:

```
QStringList list = m->stringList();
list.append("someString");
m->setStringList(list);
```

This method does work, but has one big disadvantage: The view will be reset. Any selections the user may have, sorting or the scroll-position will be lost, because the model gets reset.

**2. Using the Model:**
The second approach is the proper way of doing, but requires some more work. In this you use the functions of `QAbstractItemModel` to first add a row, and then changing it's data:

```
if(m->insertRow(m->rowCount())) {
    QModelIndex index = m->index(m->rowCount() - 1, 0);
    m->setData(index, "someString");
}
```

This one does properly update the view and keeps it's state. However, this one gets more complicated if you want to insert multiple rows, or remove/move them.

My recommendation: Use the 2. Method, because the user experience is much better. Even if you use the list in multiple places, you can get the list after inserting the row using `m->stringList()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to only use the string list provided by the `QStringListModel` - don't keep a separate copy, use `QStringListModel::stringList()` for *reading only*. To modify the list, use the model's methods: `insertRows`, `removeRows` and `setData` instead of using `QStringList` methods.